# Is there actually "confusion" over why this was closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Havning previously commented on [this closed question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70639/was-there-a-vietnam-war-computer-program-that-produced-something-like-you-won-t), I recently received [a comment](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70639/was-there-a-vietnam-war-computer-program-that-produced-something-like-you-won-t?noredirect=1#comment228876_70639)

> could you vote to re open this? Unsure as to why it was closed.. as there seems to be some confusion as to if this actually occured..?

I think I was picked as one of the commenters who didn't vote to close.

OP's motives aside, it's not clear to me whether this question is "too basic" or not -- The only resource pointed to is an article in the Atlantic Monthly, and I don't consider that a standard reference source.

Before I decide to vote to reopen, or let it drop, I'd like to hear some reasoning why the question is/isn't "too basic".

Comment: Tend to agree about the Atlantic not qualifying as a "standard reference source". That's meant to cover sources like Wikipedia, or standard encyclopedias, or whatever other such reference sources may arise for that kind of information. That doesn't mean its a great question that deserves to be open though.

Comment: @T.E.D.  Maybe a good question for Skeptics.

Comment: I do think once the Atlantic article was dug up (I read it), it does look like this story was A Thing, and its a good story, so I can see why some might want a proper answer along those lines. The question itself though ... I'm not sure we want people walking around thinking we merrily field "I vaguely remember a story" type questions.

Comment: @T.E.D. yes. I also include high school history textbooks and lower-level undergraduate textbooks as "standard reference sources", as they are widely used in mass education and designed to be broad and shallow (teach a little about a lot). Academic research-level publications and materials used in specialized graduate seminars would not normally be considered standard reference sources.